# Is it possible to set open resource (ctrl-shift-R) to search full path by default in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

When using editor like atom or sublime, when trying to open resource by hot key (e.g. ctrl-P in atom), the default behavior is to search in full path. For example, when I press ctrl-P and type `controller/base_controller`, I will see `controller/base_controller.php` in the search result.

However, in Eclipse, when I press ctrl-shift_R and type `controller/base_controller` I will get nothing. I will need to type `base_controller` (if the file name is not repeating much) or `*controller/base_controller` to have `controller/base_controller.php` in the search result.

When most OS prohibit using slash ('/') in file name, I would expect Eclipse should at least know it is a full path search when I input slash. Anyway, is there a way I can set the "open resource" search to be full path search by default in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse a full path **starts with `/`**.

So in your example, you have to type `/controller/base_controller` to match `base_controller.php` in the project `controller`.

Alternatively, you can select the project or folder and use the File Search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) leaving the *Containing text* field empty, with a file pattern and choosing the selected project or folder as scope.